# How to log the output from cmd tree command using Apache Ant exec task?

Tags: ant, cmd, exec

I am trying to log the output from cmd tree command using ant with the following:

```
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="cmd" output="output.txt">
        <arg value="tree" />
    </exec>
```

However, I am seeing the following in the "output.txt":

```
    Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
    (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
```

When I run the command in the windows cmd:

```
    C:\tree>tree
```

I get something like:

```
    C:\tree
        └───test
            └───test
```

Can anyone tell me how to write a Ant script to print the tree structure in to a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to execute `tree.com`. From the [documentation of **exec**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html):

> [...] In particular, if you do not put a
>   file extension on the executable, only
>   ".EXE" files are looked for, not
>   ".COM", ".CMD" or other file types
>   listed in the environment variable
>   PATHEXT. That is only used by the
>   shell.

You need to call `tree.com` explicitely.

```
<exec dir="${basedir}" executable="tree.com" output="output.txt" />
```

---

Another way is to specify the `/C` parameter of `cmd`, that's what worked for me:

```
<exec dir="${basedir}" executable="cmd" output="output.txt">
    <arg value="/C" />
    <arg value="tree" />
</exec>
```

Comment: I thought about suggesting `cmd /c` but thought it to be kinda redundant to invoke a shell just to call a console program. Didn't know that ant ignores PATHEXT :-)

Answer (score 1):

*(Guessing here, I'm no Ant user)*

If you would type

```
cmd tree
```

into the command prompt you also wouldn't see more than

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

What about just executing `tree`?

```
<exec dir="${basedir}" executable="tree" output="output.txt"/>
```

Comment: +1 `tree` is a regular command line application (`tree.com`) and not a built in command, so there is no need to call `cmd`

Comment: Well, I get the following error with the approach proposed:
"Cannot run program "tree": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: You might have to change it a little. TREE [drive:][path] [/F] [/A]

So executable="TREE ${basedir}"

Comment: Or even executable="TREE ${basedir} > ${basedir}\output.txt"

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error "Cannot run program "tree C:\tree": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: @Johannes: If I had known how close your answer was, when I posted the first version of mine, I would just have added a comment to yours :)

Comment: @Peter: I don't mind. I was in the wrong position of giving a correct answer anyway. The stuff about the extension is certainly a quirk one can't know when not using Ant ;-) (in fact, I still consider it kinda stupid but hey, Windows is probably one of the weirder platforms out there to support).

Comment: @Johannes: I didn't actually know about this limitation, stumbled across that part of the documentation while searching for the reason :)